# Ошибка в индексе списка: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
a =[]
n= 5
spis = 0
spismax = 0
for i in range (0,n-1):
    a.append (int(input()))
    if (a[i] <0) and (a[i+1]<0):
        spis = spis + 1 

    if spis > spismax :
        spismax = spis

print (spis)
```

Необходимо подсчитать максимальное количество подряд идущих отрицательных символов. вылезает ошибка 
in  if (a[i] <0) and (a[i+1]<0):
IndexError: list index out of range
Как ее исправить?

Comment: очевидно в тот момент когда вы обращаетесь к `a[i+1]` - в спсике `a` еще нет элемента с таким индексом...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо учитывать только отрицательные числа, а при появлении положительных начинать отсчет снова.

```
a = []
n = 5
spismax = 0
for i in range(n):
    number = int(input())
    if number < 0:
        a.append(number)
        if len(a) > spismax:
            spismax = len(a)
    else:
        a = []
print(spismax)
```

Answer (score 2):

Тот же алгоритм без использования списка:

```
n = 5
counter = 0
max_counter = 0

for i in range(n):
    number = int(input())
    if number < 0:
        counter += 1

        if counter > max_counter:
            max_counter = counter

    else:
        counter = 0

print(max_counter)
```